# Separate admin interface installation results in 404 when editing elements

Tags: api-platform.com

I installed the API platform separately (on nginx + macos), first a symfony4 project that's exposing the api to http://platform.api/api and second the react admin interface through yarn start.

The admin interface successfully loads the view and allows me to list and create new elements. But showing and editing of the different elements results in a 404 and a `Element does not exist` error message on the interface since the interface adds an additional api to the url, like http://platform.api/api/api/groups/3

Here is my App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { HydraAdmin } from '@api-platform/admin';

export default () => <HydraAdmin entrypoint="http://platform.api/api/"/>;
```

I assume that this is an issue directly on the admin react project, where the additional /api gets added. Any thoughts on how and where to configure this correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a known issue in the admin if the API is exposed in a subdirectory, and a proposal to fix it (not completed yet): https://github.com/api-platform/admin/pull/86

A quick workaround is to drop the `/api` prefix (register the API at the root). The only other solution is to finish this Pull Request.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, I'll follow the PR which looks like it'll be soon fixed.